# "Connect to Server" button stays disabled in Files on Pop!_OS, despite valid server address

Tags: linux, pop-os, nautilus

I am trying to connect to my `NAS` server from my Pop!_OS system using the "Connect to Server" feature in the Files (Nautilus) application. I navigate to "Other Locations" and enter the server address in the format `smb://server-address`. However, the "Connect" button remains greyed out and disabled, and I am unable to click it.Furthermore, when I click the `?`, the `Available Protocols` are empty (see picture below). I also created a new user account and am met with the same error when using this brand new account.

I have confirmed the server address is correct and the server is reachable because I can connect to it using the `smbclient` command-line tool.

Here's the version of my OS and Files application:

**Distributor ID:** Pop

**Description:**    Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS

**Release:**    22.04

**Codename:**   jammy

**GNOME nautilus 42.6**

I've also checked the gvfs packages and all seems to be installed correctly:

`ii  gvfs:amd64 1.48.2-0ubuntu1 amd64 userspace virtual filesystem - GIO module`

`ii  gvfs-backends 1.48.2-0ubuntu1 amd64 userspace virtual filesystem - backends`

`ii  gvfs-common 1.48.2-0ubuntu1 all userspace virtual filesystem - common data files`

`ii  gvfs-daemons 1.48.2-0ubuntu1 amd64 userspace virtual filesystem - servers`

`ii  gvfs-fuse 1.48.2-0ubuntu1 amd64 userspace virtual filesystem - fuse server`

`ii  gvfs-libs:amd64 1.48.2-0ubuntu1 amd64 userspace virtual filesystem - private libraries`

I've tried restarting the Files app and my computer, but the problem persists. I expected to be able to click "Connect" after entering a valid server address. Could this be a bug, or am I missing something?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: does `Available Protocols` show what protocols are available? is smb one of them?

Comment: Does your NAS require authentication?

Comment: And then there's [this](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gvfs/-/issues/611) ... Have you considered using NFS or SSHFS if it is indeed the above that's biting you? I mean downgrading samba sounds silly to me ... and NFS typically has better throughput/less overhead.

Comment: The NAS does require authentication. I could use NFS or SSHFS, but ultimately I'd like to get this working via Files. Also, I am unable to access the Trash as well `Sorry could not display all the contents of "trash:///": Operation not supported`!

Comment: I would expect both to be available in `files`? Surely it can't be just limited to smb ... sorry, I can't verify, I use neither gnome nor nauseous ...